# Transfer large byte arrays between javascript and java

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, web-worker

I am trying to optimise my hybrid application, currently running only on Android. My application needs to decompress many files with average size of 2MB and then pass them to JavaScript using Cordova plugin.

The native (Java) part of my application, reads through all files stored in a folder, decompress them and sends them back as byte arrays to JavaScript (If there are 50 files, I call the plugin 50 times). Once this transfer is done, the application runs perfectly smooth because everything is buffered. But while this transfer is done, my main thread is blocked.

I want to display a fading text `("Loading...")`, but the whole UI freezes. On the native part I use a ThreadPool and that's why I'm sure the problem is in my JavaScript, maybe while copying all those byte arrays from the native part. I tried to use Web Worker, but I found out I can't make a call to Cordova from it.

Is it possible to call Java using `cordova.exec` from a Web Worker. Another idea I have is to actually store the decompressed files on the SD card and make JavaScript read them from there, but I'm sure I will face some security restrictions and even if there aren't any, reading 50 files will block the thread anyways. What advise can you give me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the actual question? This would have been better simplified to something like "Call Android function from javascript (/vice versa) with a large byte array".

Comment: Yes, that sounds a little more clear, I will edit it